# Speeding up list operations in Python with C

Tags: c, performance, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Let us assume that `p` and `q` are lists in Python of common length `n`. Each list contains the contents of `range(n)` in some order (which is important!). We can assume that `n` is small (i.e. does not exceed 2^16). I now define an operation on these lists using the following code

```
def mult(p,q):
    return [q[i] for i in p]
```

Clearly `mult(p,q)` is again a list containing the contents of `range(n)` in some order. This python code is an example of the composition of permutations (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

I would like to make this code run as fast as possible in Python. I tried replacing `p` and `q` by numpy arrays to see if this would speed things up but the difference was negligible under timeit tests (note that numpy is not designed with the above function in mind). I also wrote a C extension for Python to try and speed things up but this did not seem to help (I was however using functions such as `PySequence_Fast_GET_ITEM` which are likely the same functions that Python itself uses).

Would it be possible to write a new type for Python in C (as is described here http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) which would have the property that the above `mult` function would be fast(er)? Or, indeed, write any program in C which would give Python such a type.

I am asking this question to see whether or not I am barking up the wrong tree. In particular, is there essentially some inherent property of Python which means this can never be sped up? I am mostly interested in Python 2.7 but would be interested to know of any solutions for Python 3+.

Comment: Creating the new type is easy, but have you put thought into accessing it?

Comment: Did you try `r=q[p]` in Numpy?

Comment: Have your tried PyPy? Its JIT might improve such code, but maybe not, just give it a try. (http://pypy.org/) But the main question is, how fast does it need to be? You can always optimize this kind of stuff by dropping down to something like OpenCL, as the problem is parallelizable.

Comment: Sure you can write a new type. You just have to rewrite all of the methods you intend to access from Python, which will take you 1 working month, and great pain. Your C code will be full of boilerplate and memory leaks due the ugliness and unfriendly nature of the Python API and the messing up with reference counts. And it will still be infinitely slower than a five-line function written in a true programming language

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. Especially the parallelisation comment (this is probably something to think about for the future) and @AbidRahmanK for what is undoubtably the most convenient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Abid Rahman's comment indicates, using NumPy properly is a better bet than implementing your own C datastructure.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array(range(1000))
q = np.array(range(1000))

%timeit [q[i] for i in p]
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 312 us per loop

%timeit q[p]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.31 us per loop
```

NumPy basically does what you were hoping to do yourself (push the array access down to the C level). However, if you just do a list comprehension, all the looping will be handled in Python, so it won't be much faster than the original with regular Python lists.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I wanted to do. Good to know that numpy has already implemented this without me needing to!